# Is there a significant risk to encrypt the secret with itself as key (with salt)?

Tags: encryption, encryption-symmetric

I'd like to store user passwords encrypted in a database. I need to use a bidirectional, symetrical encryption, eg. AES (using a hash is not an option in this special case).

**Part 1**
Is there a significant increased risk in using the string that I need to encrypt as the key? A public available (same row) salt is added to the key, if that matters.

**Part 2**
The same question, but applied to the following scenario:

- A is encrypted with B as the key (including salt) and
- B is encrypted with A as the key (including salt).

Both encrypted values are stored in the same database row.

Comment: What chaining mode do you plan to use? This has a significant impact on the non-salting case.

Comment: CBC is used, but I use a salt in every case.

Comment: What function are you using to transform the string into the key? Salt isn't something that is added to a key. Salting means that a nonce is injected into either the IV or the stream being encrypted or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Part 1

As long as your string password is long enough and your function to convert the string into a key is robust, then there are no special security concerns attached to using a string password this way.

### Part 2

To prevent against replay attacks involving the first block, you should always salt. Either inject a nonce into the IV, or inject at the head of the stream being encrypted.